# Convert SQL raw query into Linq

Tags: linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have 3 tables (activities, participants and enrollments) and I want to know the number of activities that each participant participated into.I am new in writing SQL Linq query please help me to convert the below query into Linq.

```
Select count(Activities.ActivityId) AS NO_Activities,Activities.ActivityId,Enrollments.PostTestScore1
from Participants,Activities,Enrollments
where Participants.ParticipantId=Enrollments.ParticipantId
    and Activities.ActivityId=Enrollments.ActivityId
    and Enrollments.ParticipantId= 2883
    Group By Enrollments.PostTestScore1,Activities.ActivityId;
```

Thanks

Comment: Please never just post SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, tell what type of LINQ you're targeting (to entities?), and show your own first efforts so we see where *specifically* you need help. The best LINQ query is hardly ever a 1:1 reproduction of a SQL query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer using Lambda query as below.

```
var no_ctivities = db.Activities
               .Join(
                   db.Enrollments,
                   ac => ac.ActivityId,
                   en => en.ActivityId,
                   (enr, act) => new { en = enr, ac = act })
               .Join(
                   db.Participants.Where(pr => pr.ParticipantId == id),
                   en => en.ac.ParticipantId,
                   prt => prt.ParticipantId,
                   (enr, prt) => new { enr.ac.PostTestScore1, enr.ac.PostTestScore2, enr.ac.ActivityId, enr.ac.AttendFirstday, enr.ac.AttendSecondDay })
               .Select(c => new
               {
                   c.ActivityId,
                   c.PostTestScore1,
                   c.PostTestScore2,
                   c.AttendFirstday,
                   c.AttendSecondDay
               }).count();
```

Comment: This is a different query. Where's the count? Also, you should use navigation properties, no joins.

Answer (score 2):

```
var query = from a1 in Activities
            join e1 in Enrollments on a1.ActivityId equals e1.ActivityId
            join p1 in Participants on e1.ParticipantId equals p1.ParticipantId
            where e1.ParticipantId= 2883
            group new { e1, a1 }
            by new { e1.PostTestScore1, a1.ActivityId } into g
            select new
            {
                 ActivityId = g.Key.ActivityId,
                 PostTestScore1 = g.Key.PostTestScore1,
                 NO_Activities = g.Count()
            };
```

Comment: Thanks it also helped me but with a small changes.

Comment: I approved the changes